# F:selectItems showing the class not a value

Tags: jsf

I'm new to facelets and I have generated a project using netbeans but I struggling with the  tag.

I have

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{organisation.organisation.country}" title="Country" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{country.countryItemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

In the select I get classpath.Country[iso=GB] which I can see is an object but I really want to see the the country.prinableName value. 
I've looked at this for half a day and have drawn a blank
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8):

Since you're talking about Facelets, I'll assume JSF 2.x.

To start, HTML is one and all String. JSF generates HTML. By default, non-`String` Java objects are by `toString()` method converted to their `String` representation while JSF generates the HTML. To properly convert between those Java objects and `String`, you need a [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html).

I assume that your `Country` object has already the `equals()` method [properly implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract/3181374#3181374), otherwise validation will later fail with "Validation error: Value not valid" because the selected object doesn't return `true` on testing the `equals()` for any of the available items.

I'll also make a little change in the naming since `#{country}` is a confusing managed bean name because it does apparently not represent an instance of the `Country` class. I'll call it `Data` which should hold application wide data.

```java
@ManagedBean
@ApplicaitionScoped
public class Data {

    private static final List<Country> COUNTRIES = populateItSomehow();

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return COUNTRIES;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'll assume that the `Country` class has two properties `code` and `name`. I'll assume that the managed bean which receives the selected country has a `private Country country` property. In your `<f:selectItems>`, you need to loop over `#{data.countries}` and specify the country object as item value and the country name as item label.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.country}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Now, you need to create a `Converter` for the `Country` class. We'll convert based on the country code which is unique for every country (right?). In the `getAsString()` you implement code which converts the Java object to its unique String representation which is to be used in HTML. In `getAsObject()` you implement code which converts the unique HTML String representation back to the Java object.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Country.class)
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return (value instanceof Country) ? ((Country) value).getCode() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Data data = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{data}", Data.class);

        for (Country country : data.getCountries()) {
            if (country.getCode().equals(value)) {
                return country;
            }
        }

        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to Country", value)));
    }

}
```

The `@FacesConverter` will register it automatically in JSF and JSF will automatically use it whenever it encounters a value expression of the `Country` type. Ultimately, you end up with country code as item value and country name as item label. JSF will convert the submitted country code back to a fullworthy `Country` object upon form submission.

In JSF 1.x the principle is not much different. In this blog you can find two basic kickoff examples: [Objects in `h:selectOneMenu`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html).

Comment: Thank you all your assumptions correct and a great explanation will work through the example it will help me else where as well

Answer (score 1):

What happened to you, [`selectOneMenu`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlSelectOneMenu.html) call the [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method for all given objects.

You've to use [`selectitems`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) or a simple [`converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) to manage that. A very simple example:

**price.xhtml:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="priceMenu" value="#{priceBean.selectedPrice}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{priceBean.prices}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**PriceBean.java:**

```
..
private String selectedPrice;
..
public String getSelectedPrice() {
    return selectedPrice;
}

public void setSelectedPrice(String newPrice) {
    selectedPrice = newPrice;
}
..
public List<SelectItem> getPrices() {
    List<SelectItem> retVal = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    retVal.add(new SelectItem("2"));
    retVal.add(new SelectItem("4"));
    retVal.add(new SelectItem("6"));

    return retVal;
}
```

Further informations about the [`SelectItem`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html). If you want to use a specially object directly, for example an object called `Price`, you have to use a converter. [Here an example is shown](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/70-create-simple-custom-converter-implementation.html) [and here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf3/#N10239).

Answer (score 0):

If you add `editable="true"` in your

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.country}">
```

Then you'll get an unexpected `String` value (not from `getAsString()`) in the converter method:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) { }
```