# JSF - selectItems doesn't render list inside of list

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, jstl

I have the following facelet code which is failing:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:select defaultLabel="Seleccionar región">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.regiones}" var="region" itemValue="#{region.reg_Cod}" itemLabel="#{region.reg_Nombre}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="provs" />
    </rich:select>
    <rich:select id="provs" defaultLabel="Seleccionar provincia">
    <f:selectItems value="#{region.provincias}" var="prov" itemValue="#{prov.prov_Cod}" itemLabel="#{prov.prov_Nombre}" />
    </rich:select>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
public class StaticInfoBean {

    private ArrayList<Region> regiones;

    public StaticInfoBean() {
        try
        {
            RegionDAO regDao = new RegionDAO();
            regDao.prepareConnection();
            ProvinciaDAO provDao = new ProvinciaDAO();
            provDao.setCon(regDao.getCon());
            ComunaDAO comDao = new ComunaDAO();
            comDao.setCon(regDao.getCon());
            regiones = regDao.listaRegiones();
            for(Region r : regiones)
            {
                regDao.findProvincias(r);
                for(Provincia p : r.getProvincias())
                {
                    provDao.findComunas(p);
                    for(Comuna c : p.getComunas())
                    {
                        comDao.findColegios(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            regDao.getCon().close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Region> getRegiones() {
        return regiones;
    }

    public void setRegiones(ArrayList<Region> regiones) {
        this.regiones = regiones;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return regiones.toString();
    }

}
```

Class `Region`:

```
public class Region {

    private String Reg_Cod;
    private String Reg_Nombre;
    private ArrayList<Provincia> provincias;
//Getters and setters
```

The problem: The first `rich:select` tag works just fine. However the second one doesn't display any value. Not just that, but I'm working in NetBeans and it doesn't display the list of methods for class `Provincia` whenever I type "prov" in the EL.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I edited my code and did the following:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:select defaultLabel="Seleccionar región" value="#{StaticInfo.regionElegida}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.regiones}" var="region" itemValue="#{region.reg_Cod}" itemLabel="#{region.reg_Nombre}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="click" render="provs" execute="@this" />
        <a4j:ajax event="click" render="texto" execute="@this" />
    </rich:select>
<h:outputText id="texto" value="#{StaticInfo.regionElegida.reg_Nombre}" />
    <rich:select id="provs" defaultLabel="Seleccionar provincia" value="#{StaticInfo.provinciaElegida}" rendered="#{not empty StaticInfo.regionElegida}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.regionElegida.provincias}" var="prov" itemValue="#{prov.prov_Cod}" itemLabel="#{prov.prov_Nombre}" />
    </rich:select>
</h:form>
```

What's surprising is that the outputText isn't being displayed! Why would this happen?

Comment: is there any error showing up in the console?

Comment: Nope, all I get is a "null" output.

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?

Comment: Request. The values must be loaded each time they're needed in case there's a change in the db during the session.

Comment: Is this the full code of your bean?

Comment: Yes, it's the full code. Nothing's missing.

Comment: I edited my post and found a related error, yet I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The outputText you mention is missing on your post. Anyway, you don't need to specify two `a4j:ajax`, you can simply separate ids with spaces, as in `render="provs texto"`.

Comment: The outputText is there, look below in my edit. And yeah, I could have done it that way but I'm just debugging. I just added a valueChangeListener to set the value but it's not working either...

Comment: I just now realized that you are missing the code to deal with `region.reg_Cod`... Let me update the code to help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `region` set in `f:selectItems` is only available inside its scope.
You have to bind each `rich:select` to a backing bean property.

So, you need to change your bean code, adding properties for the chosen region to the bean:

```
public class StaticInfoBean {    
    private ArrayList<Region> regiones;
    private Region regionElegida;
    private Provincia provinciaElegida; // <-- you'll probably want this too...

    // ... getters and setters and your initialization code

    // and you need something to find the real region object that
    // used the reg_Cod value got from rich:select, for now you can try this:
    public void updateRegionElegida(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){
        // set the chosen region to regionElegida,
        // or the poor man's converter
        for (Region region : regiones){
            if(regionElegida.getReg_Cod() == region.getReg_cod()) {
                regionElegida = region;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then change your XHTML to something like this:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:select value="#{StaticInfo.regionElegida}"
          defaultLabel="Seleccionar región">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.regiones}" var="region"
             itemValue="#{region.reg_Cod}" itemLabel="#{region.reg_Nombre}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="provs"
             listener="#{StaticInfo.updateRegionElegida}" />
    </rich:select>
    <rich:select id="provs" value="#{StaticInfo.provinciaElegida}"
          defaultLabel="Seleccionar provincia">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.regionElegida.provincias}" var="prov"
            itemValue="#{prov.prov_Cod}" itemLabel="#{prov.prov_Nombre}" />
    </rich:select>
</h:form>
```

Now, the professional way of doing that conversion thing would be to use a custom converter that can find the appropriate instance of a Region object based on the value of the expression `itemValue` used for its select widget. Check out [this example from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354975/149872).

Note that `rich:select` only adds functionality to the default `h:selectOneMenu`, you would do good checking out [its info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) here at SO.

Comment: I'd love to say it's working, but it's not. I get the same error, the second `rich:select` doesn't display any value.

Comment: still nothing in the console?

Comment: @user1231958 I've updated my answer, with more info about dealing with the value from `rich:select`/`h:selectOneMenu`. Please, have a look at that page, it explains a lot of this stuff, with a lot of free examples. :)

Comment: Oh god my error was much dumber than I thought - I didn't initialize a list in a constructor!! Thank you very much!!