# Custom converter Error in h:SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem implementing a custom converter...

my xhtml is:

```html
...
<span class="cien">
    <h:outputLabel value="Director de Area Correspondiente:" 
        styleClass="negritas" />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ordenBO.director}" id="director-area" 
        converter="superiorAuditoriaConverter" 
        converterMessage="Error al seleccionar el Director">
        <f:selectItems value="#{ordenBO.directores}"></f:selectItems>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:message for="director-area"></p:message>
</span>    
...
```

this is how I fill my h:SelectOneMenu:

```java
...
this.directores = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for (SuperiorAuditoriaDTO sup: daoSuperiorAuditoria.getDirectoresASM())
    this.directores.add(new SelectItem(sup, sup.getProfesion() + " " +
        sup.getNombre_completo()));
...
```

this is my Custom converter:

```java
....
@FacesConverter(forClass = SuperiorAuditoriaDTO.class, value = 
    "superiorAuditoriaConverter")
public class SuperiorAuditoriaConverter implements Converter {

    private static SuperiorAuditoriaDAO dao = new SuperiorAuditoriaDAO();

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String id_persona) { 
    SuperiorAuditoriaDTO s = null;
    try {
        s = dao.getSuperiorASM(Integer.parseInt(id_persona));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object auditor) {
    return String.valueOf(((SuperiorAuditoriaDTO) auditor).getId_persona());
}

}
```

Can somebody help me?? I always got an error message saying that the value that I try to convert is not valid..

I'm using jsf 2 mojarra... 
and I also have equals and hashCode method implemented...

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> *I always got an error message saying that the value that I try to convert is not valid.*

Thus, you got "Validation error: Value not valid"? That will happen when the `equals()` method on the selected object has not returned `true` for any of the available select items. In other words, the `equals()` method of `SuperiorAuditoriaDTO` is broken. Fix it accordingly.

#### See also:

- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract/3181374#3181374)