# How to access HashMap in JSP by Object key (rather than String)

Tags: java, jsp, el

I can access a `HashMap<String, Object>` easily enough in JSTL but is it possible to access a `HashMap<Object, Object>`

I only ask because I don't receive any errors (or output) when trying the following:

```
${myHashMap[anObject]}
```

It leads me to believe that myHashMap is trying to find my value but it is somehow not evaluating `anObject` as the correct key. I can verify that myHashMap has `anObject` as a key with a (non-blank/non-null) value that should display.

Comment: Look at the signature of `HashMap` in the javadoc.  The `get` method takes `Object`, not `K`. Anyway, it's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: I'm starting to think there is a conspiracy but I will gently ask - @skaffman What is not clear about my question?

Comment: You didn't state the concrete problem very clearly. The phrase *"however the key is incorrect"* is ambiguous, for example.

Comment: Edited - I'll get better at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax ought indeed to work. I understand that you didn't get any value by the given object as key although you're confident that the desired object is in there? In that case, the class as represented behind `${anObject}` in your code must have the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) methods properly implemented. The [`Map#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) namely tests the key by `equals()` method. See also the javadoc:

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>
> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this method returns v; otherwise it returns `null`. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

In other words, if the `equals()` of your `${anObject}` returns `true` for the map key, then the associated map value will be returned, otherwise `null` will be returned and EL will then print nothing.

That it works for `String` is simply because that class has the `equals()` [already](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) properly implemented.

#### See also:

- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract)