# Validation Error: value is not valid when using a custom converter

Tags: validation, jsf-2, converters

NetBeans 7.1.1 JSF2.1

When using converter="convK" attribute in h:selectManyCheckBox it all works well. But I tried to use @FacesConverter(forClass=className.class) form and it keeps giving me "Validation is not Valid" errors. I've tried changing it to forClass=packageName.className.class but no help.

This is converter:

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
 @FacesConverter( "convK")
  public class KorisnikConverter implements Converter{
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
     if (value==null) return value;
     if (value.isEmpty()) return value;
        for (int i=0; i<Arhiva.getSviKor().size(); i++) {
            if (Arhiva.getSviKor().get(i).getUsername().equals(value)) {
                return Arhiva.getSviKor().get(i);
            }
        }
     return value;
}
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value==null) return "";
    if (value instanceof Korisnik) return ((Korisnik)value).getUsername();
    return "";
}   
}
```

I have a class called Korisnik which has couple text fields, username is unique one. In my main managing bean I have couple arrayList of those objects. Goal is to use selectManyCheckBox to chose just some of users and put them in a separate arraylist for some other uses. I wanted to push entire objects around (I can always easily work with strings and have object creation and management in my controler beans but wanted to try custom converters to get selectItems to work  with objects)

In my class I've overridden equals and hashCode (as there is a lot of talk about custom converters giving blah blah Validation is not valid errors).

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (obj==null) return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Korisnik)) return false;
    Korisnik k = (Korisnik)obj;
    return (this.username==k.username);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.username.hashCode();
}
```

Edit. When I'm using it as named converter and using said converter only in that one instance with selectManyCheckbox it works fine even without overriding equals and hashCode.

This is checkbox code

```
  <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{kontrolg.izabrAut}" layout="pageDirection" converter="convK" >
              <f:selectItems value="#{kontrolg.moguciAut}" var="it" itemLabel="#    {it.ime}&#160;#{it.prezime}" itemValue="#{it}"/>
      </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

What I don't know is whether I'm failing to properly use forClass="whatever" in converter annotation or my converter actually works ok with that one selectManyCheckbox, but when I specify it in forClass form it gets used for all instances of that object and causes some other code that worked nice before adding custom converters to now give "validation is not valid" error?

Answer (score 0):

The `value is not valid` validation error will be thrown when the `equals()` method on the selected item has **not** returned `true` for *any* of the available items.

And indeed, your `equals()` method is broken. The following line is wrong:

```
return (this.username==k.username);
```

I'll assume that `username` is a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), which is an [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). The `==` compares `Object`s by **reference**, not by their **value**. In other words, when performing `==` on two `Object`s, you're basically testing if they point to exactly the same instance. You're not checking if they represent the same value (say, the `Object` instance's internal representation). You should be using the `Object`'s `equals()` method instead, the [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, here's an extract of relevance from its javadoc:

> #### equals
>
> `public boolean equals(Object anObject)`
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and is a `String` object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

The `==` is only applicable when comparing primitives like `boolean`, `int`, `long`, etc or when testing for `null`.

So, to fix your problem, replace the wrong line by the following line:

```
return username.equals(k.username);
```

Or, when they can possibly be `null`:

```
return (username == null) ? (k.username == null) : username.equals(k.username);
```

#### See also:

- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it isn't working still. I changed check to equals (I forgot about that because I was reusing equals() code I saw in help answers for other people asking about Validation Error: Value is not valid.

Comment: I also tried using NetBeans to generate equals and hashCode.... same error. And I'm completely puzzled why it works 100% even without overriding equals and hash code when I specify converter by name as attribute of h:selectManyCheckBox. Also, forgot to mention. I don't get error on page load, just when I click submit on that checkbox form. Which works without errors if I name the converter and dont use forClass...