# How to pre-select data in h:selectManyListbox

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

This is a common problem and I already saw the basic solution (populate the `selectManyListBox`). Here is the code of my JSF 1.2 page:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="statusMenu" converter="statusConverter" value="#{aprvAction.ap.statuses}" >
    <f:selectItems id="statusItem" value="#{action.ap.statusItens}"/>
    <a:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true" eventsQueue="queueGeral" />
    <a:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" eventsQueue="queueGeral" process="statusMenu"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

The thing is that `#{aprvAction.ap.statuses}` is an instance of `List<Status>` class. However, in tag `<f:selectItems>` the value: `#{action.ap.statusItens}` is an Instance of `List<SelectItem>`.

I populate the the `#{aprvAction.ap.statuses}` with the values that I want to pre-select the ListBox, but did not work. I think it's because they are different objects in `<selectManyListBox>` and `<selectItems>`.

How can I solve this, and show the pre-selected values in `<selectManyListBox>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF will use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method to compare available items with (pre)selected items.

In case of standard objects, such as `String`, this is [already implemented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

In case of custom objects, such as your `Status` entity, it's your responsibility to make sure that you've properly implemented the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method in the class.

#### See also:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-with-complex-objects-entities-from-a-db)
- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract/)

Comment: Okay, just to see if I got it right. `selectManyListbox` value refers to `List<Status>`, and `selectItems` value refers to `List<SelectItem>`. Do I need to implement the `equals()` method in `Status` entity? Do I need to compare with `SelectItem` object inside my entity? Is this right?

Comment: No. The `SelectItem` has a `Status` as value, right?

Comment: Yes! My mistake! You are absolutely right. I implemented the `equals()` method and the `hashCode()` method and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`value` in `h:selectManyListbox` should be subset of `itemValue`'s in `f:selectItems`.

Create a method which return the List or Array of selected statuses. Use this method in `value` attribute of `h:selectManyListbox`. Any value from list/array returned in this method should match itemValue in set of {itemValue, itemLabel} pairs used in `f:selectItems`.

Comment: I do that and I got this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument Error: An option for component statusMenu was not an instance of javax.faces.model.SelectItem.  Type found: java.util.ArrayList.` This ArrayList is na List of `Status` object.