# JSF: How to bind many of h:selectBooleanCheckbox?

Tags: jsf, binding, checkbox

I have a problem to bind list of h:selectBooleanCheckbox to my bean.
Anybody helps ?

This is not working:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cartBean.productsList}" var="cartProduct" varStatus="i">
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{cartBean.checkboxes[i.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>

public class CartBean extends BaseBean {
  public List<Product> getProductsList() {...}

  private HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox[] checkboxes;
  public HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox[] getCheckboxes() {
    return checkboxes;
  }
  public void setCheckboxes(HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox[] checkboxes) {
    this.checkboxes = checkboxes;
  }
}
```

I get error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/flows/main/cart.xhtml @26,97 binding="#{cartBean.checkboxes[i.index]}": Target Unreachable, 'checkboxes' returned null
```

---

I solved my problem. I used code like below and get what i want (thanks to BalusC blog - http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SelectMultipleRows):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cartBean.productsList}" var="cartProduct" varStatus="i">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cartBean.selectedIds[cartProduct.id]}" />
</ui:repeat>

public class CartBean extends BaseBean {
  private Map<Integer, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
  public Map<Integer, Boolean> getSelectedIds() {
    return selectedIds;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p

Answer (score 2):

Your concrete problem is caused because the `binding` attribute is evaluated during view build time, that moment when the XHTML source code is turned into a JSF UI component tree, while the `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time, that moment when the JSF UI component tree needs to produce HTML.

In other words, the `#{i.index}` is only available during view render time and evaluates as `null` during view build time. In effects, you're doing a `binding="#{cartBean.checkboxes[null]}"`

There's another conceptual mistake here: you seem to expect that the `<ui:repeat>` produces physically multiple `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` components. This is untrue. There's physically **only one** `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` which is reused multiple times to produce HTML based on the currently iterated variable. Actually, `binding="#{cartBean.checkbox}"` was been sufficient. However, collecting the values is a story apart. I won't go in detail, but you can find several hints in this answer: [Validate order of items inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469551/validate-order-of-items-inside-uirepeat/18470293#18470293).

In order to achieve the (apparent) concrete functional requirement of generating physically multiple `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` components and binding each to a separate array item, you should be using an iteration component which runs during view build time instead of view render time. That's the JSTL `<c:forEach>`:

```
<c:forEach items="#{cartBean.productsList}" var="cartProduct" varStatus="i">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{cartBean.checkboxes[i.index]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

But, after all, using `binding` on a bean property should be avoided as much as possible. Use instead exactly that attribute which you ultimately need: the `value` attribute. This way you don't need to do a `HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox#getValue()` everytime. You already figured the right solution with a `Map<Integer, Boolean> selectedIds`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cartBean.productsList}" var="cartProduct">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cartBean.selectedIds[cartProduct.id]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can bind elements stored in an array. But in your code, the problem is that your `HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox[]` is `null`. So maybe change your Java code to:

```
public HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox[] getCheckboxes() {
    if (checkboxes == null) {
        checkboxes = new HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox[getProductsList().size()];
    }
    return checkboxes;
}
```

but I am really not sure if it will work... Maybe the solution is to not bind your `HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox` elements in the Java code. Why do you need to bind them?

Comment: Thanks for Your replay, but now i get error: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/flows/main/cart.xhtml @26,97 binding="#{cartBean.checkboxes[i.index]}": Target Unreachable, 'BracketSuffix' returned null