# input.setValid(false) does not have any effect when component is inside <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I need to mark inputText field generated using ui:repeat as invalid. I am able to do it for normal input fields by using following code in bean:

```
 UIComponent root = context.getViewRoot();
 UIInput inputFieldObj = obj.findComponent(root, id);
 inputFieldObj .setValid(false);
```

The above code is working, however when I try to get the components that are generated using ui:repeat. Its not marking the textfield as invalid.

So for below code its working:

```
<p:inputText id="txtEmpId12" />
```

But for this its not:

```
<ui:repeat>
    <p:inputText id="txtEmpId" />   
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: what happen.. why my question has been voted down?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your scenario component tree contains only one input. `Ui:repeat` renders inputs on render phase. As a workaround you could use `c:forEach`. In this case component tree will contain all inputs. But I don't like this approach.

Comment: I still don't get how it contains single input. iSs it internal property of ui:repeat? When I have a list size of 3, using ui:repeat, its generating 3 input fields with unique id's like id = '0:txtEmpId, id='1:txtEmpId, id='2:txtEmpId. so, hows its a one input? I just want to understand. Please clarify.

Comment: Take a look at this link: [Validate order of items inside ui:repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469551/validate-order-of-items-inside-uirepeat)