# How to validate multiple Primefaces calendar elements?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have a [PrimeFaces dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml), where each row contains two [PrimeFaces calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) popup elements (FromDate, ToDate). I want to make sure two date ranges are not equal. I tried using [Omnifaces validateMultiple](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple) but couldn't get it to work. Rows can be dynamically added and removed from the table by the user, so I don't know how many there are.

How do I address those elements in Omnifaces? As far as I see, only IDs can be used, no classes. Also, Omnifaces doesn't know something like jQuery selectors/PFS.

What would be a better solution to this? I'd prefer a solution using plain JSF, Omnifaces or Primefaces.

**//edit Feb 12, '16:** 
I found [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/multi-components-validator-in-jsf-2-0/) on how to validate multiple components using PrimeFaces. The tutorial works, but it doesn't solve my issue. The thing is, I cannot get the values of all the date pickers to check. I can only [search them by ID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-), which is not sufficient, as they can be added and removed by the user. I also tried getting the surrounding DataTable and friggle the individual date pickers out. This also does not work since the UINamingContainer I get does not contain the value of the date picker.

Comment: You mean, in each row you can select a date range, and you'd like to validate it against all other rows in the same table that they don't overlap?

Comment: @BalusC: yes, that's it!

Comment: As per your edit about that tutorial, this related Q&A should give clues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18469551

Comment: @BalusC: Issue solved. The link you referenced helped alot! Thanks!