# understanding ajax execute behavior with datatable using jsf 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

i'm trying to use an **search button** which brings back the selected items (can be more than one) and it updates the datatable. Then i have a selectBooleanCheckbox next to each colomn, when user selects "n" items then presses the **Select the checked Items** it insert DB.

The code can be seen below:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="5">
    <h:form>
      <h:outputText value="Item Name"/>
      <p:inputText value="#{StockController.itemName}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{StockController.Search}">
         <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results"/>
      </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

//The code sample below belongs to BalusC see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266189/how-to-delete-many-row-in-hdatatable-with-checkbox)

```
    <h:panelGroup id="results">
    <h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[entity.id]}" />
        </h:column>
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Select the checked Items" action="#{StockController.insertDao}" >
  <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results"/>
 </h:commandButton>
 </h:form>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Now, i have read many blogs and Core javaServer Faces 3, i don't think there is logical error in ajax usage. I tested by removing each ajax then **both works fine** but whenever i try to use **both of cummondButtons** with ajax, the second one "**Select the checked Items**" does not even call the **"StockController.insertDao"** method.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to ajax-render content which in turn contains another form, then you need to include the ID of that form in the `render` attribute as well, otherwise the other form will lose its view state and nothing will be processed on submit.

```
<h:form>
  ...
  <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{StockController.Search}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results :resultsForm" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="results">
  <h:form id="resultsForm">
    ...
  </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If there's however nothing which goes outside `<h:form>` inside the same `<h:panelGroup>`, then you can just omit the `<h:panelGroup>` altogether and re-render the form directly.

```
<h:form>
  ...
  <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{StockController.Search}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="results">
  ...
</h:form>
```

This is related to [JSF spec issue 790](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790).

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF2 - Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm)

Comment: thank you very much just start learning jsf and make this kind of errors easily. Now i got it. i also want to say that i'm a big fan of your blog and responses.

Comment: You're welcome. I wouldn't immediately say that this one is your own mistake. This is not intuitive. It's just a bug/oversight in the JSF spec which needs to be workarounded until they fix it.