# Save all rows in an h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a Facelets page with a `h:dataTable.` In each row of the `h:dataTable`, i am displaying some enabled and disabled services of a user.Here is the model object

```
public class ServiceList {

    private long userId;
    private long serviceGroupId;
    private String serviceGroupName;
    private long serviceId;
    private String serviceName;
    private String serviceUrl;
    private String serviceState;

    public UserServiceList() {
    }
//getters and setters....
}
```

These are the details i am displaying in a single row of a dataTable.
serviceState in the above model object is either 'Y' or 'N'.

**my problem is the application user should be able to update the servicestate of all rows of a dataTable at once and update them in the backend database.**

1)what additional JSF component do i need to use inside dataTable to achive this? I am thinking of adding one more column with h:selectOneradio

2)How do i get which rows are selected and what status they have set?

I am kind of newbee to JSF.Please help.

**Update**:At present what i am having is two buttons namely 'Disable Service' and 'Enable Service' in the footer section of the table.

Onclick of Disable Service i am navigating to another page where i show the application user the list of enabled services to disable

And vice-versa for Enabled service button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's say you in your *Managed Bean* you have a list of services you would like the user to edit:

```
List<Service> serviceList;
```

You take this `List` to be displayed in the data table.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{yourManagedBean.serviceList}" ... >
```

Then you can implement a `commandButton` that has either an `action` or an `actionListener` which points to a certain method of your managed bean, like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{yourManagedBean.saveAllAction}" ... >
```

And the corresponding method to save 'em all is quite straight-forward. You iterate over the managed bean field `serviceList` and persist every single entry (however you persist them, like calling the `EntityManager` when using Hibernate or any DAO class in between, you name it.)

Concerning the service status: I'd preferably use a `selectBooleanCheckbox` for toggling the status, since it's probably a boolean value.

*Edit after comment 1:*

You have the `serviceStatus` in your `Service` class. Currently it's a string, but I suppose it should be boolean to toggle active/inactive. If this property is displayed by the `selectBooleanCheckbox` it is automatically changed in your corresponding Java class. So calling `getServiceStatus()` returns `true` or `false`, depending on what is selected in the frontend. If you persist the whole `Service` object then, you don't have to do anything because any modifications made in the frontend HTML elements are automatically projected to the Java object behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sebastian.Can you be more clear about storing the changed row's id's?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question. This should help. Otherwise I'd recommend reading some stuff about how Java/JSF works in this direction. You have the basic structure of how you do this - saving the Service depends on your environment, so I can only explain generically.

Comment: Thanks once again Sebastian.I solved the storing selected rows from this link                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-pe[link]

Comment: I used selectoneRadio to display the user with options to disable or Enable.I linked it to serviceStatus in the Service class as you said.  That Solved my problem.Now i am able to get which row is selected and the status which user selects.Thanks for the help.