# Make h:dataTable cell editable by using h:selectbooleanCheckbox linked to HashMap in the bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I went through this question from SO 
[How to use <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> in <h:dataTable> to select multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-pe)

Using the single checkbox as shown in above question i want to find out whether i can make h:datatable cell editable so that user can edit all the rows and columns at once and submit

Here is part of bean class

```
public class bean {
private List<Group> GroupList;

private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

public void setChecked(Map<Long, Boolean> checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public Map<Long, Boolean> getChecked() {
    return checked;
}


}
```

And here is my JSF page

```
<h:dataTable id="editTable" styleClass = "listtable" value="#{bean.GroupList}"  var="group" border="1" first="0" rows="8" width="75%" frame="hsides" rules="all" cellpadding="5" headerClass="tableheading" rowClasses="firstrow, secondrow">

    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Groups"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="GroupId"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered=""></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered=""/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="GroupName"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered=""></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered=""/>
    </h:column>


    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Check to Enable/Disable"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" />
    </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

What should be kept in **rendered** attribute so that when it is checked h:inputtext is rendered and when not checked h:outputtext is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind to the same property. It returns a `Boolean` anyway. You can use `!` or `not` to negate it.

```
<h:outputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered="#{!bean.checked[group.Id]}" />
<h:inputText value="#{group.Id}" rendered="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" />
...
<h:outputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered="#{!bean.checked[group.Id]}" />
<h:inputText value="#{group.Name}" rendered="#{bean.checked[group.Id]}" />
```

Comment: @BalusC-Thanks for the response.but nothing is happening when i do it.i tried with ! and not also.

Comment: You must submit the form after checking the checkbox. Your bean must be in session (or view) scope instead of request scope.

Comment: No i didnt submit the form.Yes my bean is session scoped.i should make it request scoped?

Comment: You must submit the form to get the checkbox values to be applied and the page to be re-rendered. Session scope is fine (it's only a bit too broad, the bean is now shared between all other browser tabs/windows which may lead to unexpected results when interacting with the same page in multiple windows/tabs, I'd prefer Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>`).

Comment: if i make like this  `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[group.Id]} onclick="submit()" />`                                                                    Is it correct?

Comment: You can do so. It will only also submit all other inputs in the same form which might lead to fighting with validation like `required="true"`. If you were using JSF 2.x, it would be much easier/better with ajax powers.

Comment: I am using only JSF 1.2.What is the better way to handle it?

Comment: Upgrade to JSF 2 :) Or look for an ajax-flavored component library like RichFaces/Ajax4jsf.

Comment: Ok.Out of all the implementations of JSF.which one is the best one?

Comment: There are only two major JSF implementations: Mojarra and MyFaces. Choosing should be based on its robustness. But switching between JSF implementations should be relatively transparent and easy as it's just a matter of replacing the JAR files and changing some implementation-specific context parameters, if any. I myself are using Mojarra 2.1.3 which is a JSF 2.1 implementation which requires a Servlet 3.0 container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc). But if you're still using a Servlet 2.5 container (Tomcat 6, Glassfish 2, etc), then you should use JSF 2.0, not JSF 2.1.