# How to add ice:selectManyCheckbox to a ice:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have a `<ice:dataTable>` and I want to add a checkbox to each row. I tried to add a `<ice:selectManyCheckbox>`, but it shows an empty column and the checkboxes doesn't appear.

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox id="customTransChbx" partialSubmit="true">
    <f:selectItems id="SlctLangItms" value="#{employee.s}" />
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>

<ice:dataTable id="employeedatatable" value="#{employee.model}" var="emp" rows="5">
    <ice:column>
        <ice:checkbox for="customTransChbx" index="#{emp.id}" rendered="true" />
    </ice:column>
</ice:dataTable>
```

How can I select multiple rows by checkboxes in a `<ice:dataTable>`?

---

**Update**: I also tried `<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>` with a `Map`:

```
public class Employee {

    private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

    public void preRender(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws Exception {
        List<Employee> list = employeeService.getEmployees();

        for (Employee employee : list)
            checked.put(employee.getId(), false);
        }
    }
```

with

```
<ice:dataTable id="employeedatatable" value="#{employee.model}" var="emp" rows="5">
    <ice:column>
        <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{employee.checked[emp.id]}" />
    </ice:column>
</ice:dataTable>
```

When trying to get the checked list in an action method, all the values in the map are `false`, even the selected ones. Why are the checked values not put in the `Map`?

UPDATE2: i tried the old plain html way, as follows:

- defining the checkbox as input:

  `<input type="checkbox" name="toDelete" value="#{emp.id}" />`
- getting the checked values in the backing bean method as follows:

`HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String[] checkedValues = request.getParameterValues("toDelete");`

problem is that the checkedValues  array is always null ?

Comment: Seems like it should work. Perhaps it's a bug or limitation in IceFaces. You can always try a combination of `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` and a `HashMap`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p/2524832#2524832

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't work too, please see the question update.

Comment: You actually don't need to prefill the list at all. But that shouldn't be the problem. Sorry, I don't know. It'll be something specific to IceFaces.

Comment: even if i changed all the above code to use JSF core not icefaces, still getting same behavior.

Comment: Then your data preserving logic is not correct. You need to ensure that `#{employee.model}` is properly preserved for the request of processing the form submit. Easiest is to put the bean in the view scope.

Comment: i already tried view scope, and still getting same behavior.

Comment: i tried another way, question is updated, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure that the **datatable** and the **button** are in the same **form**.