# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

My entity has bean validation annotations `@NotBlank` and `@Size` on the `name` field. However, when I submit the JSF form with the `name` field left blank, it doesn't validate the field.

Here's the field in question:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{name.required}")
@Size(max = 25, message = "{long.value}")
@Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false)
private String name;
```

When submitting the form without entering any data, I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.myapp.domain.Department] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.myapp.domain.Department] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy212.addDepartment(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.beans.DepartmentBean.addOrUpdateDepartment(DepartmentBean.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
```

How is this caused and now can I solve it?

---

**Update:** here's the relevant part of the view:

```
<h:form>         
    <ice:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel>Department Name:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{departmentBean.departmentObj.name}" />
        <h:message for="name" />
    </ice:panelGrid>        
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <ice:panelGroup>
        <h:commandLink value="Add New" action="#{departmentBean.addOrUpdateDepartment}" />
    </ice:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stacktrace:

```
at com.myapp.beans.DepartmentBean.addOrUpdateDepartment(DepartmentBean.java:105)
...
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
```

This means that your JSF bean action method is invoked anyway while this should have been blocked by the validation constraints on the empty `name` field and you should have seen a validation error in a `<h:message>` or `<h:messages>` of the form.

That can only mean that you've put `immeditate="true"` on the command button/link which would cause all input components which don't have this attribute will be skipped in form processing:

```
<h:commandButton ... immediate="true" />
```

or that you've this context parameter in your `web.xml` which would skip validation of empty fields:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or that you have disabled the bean validation in your view by the following tag:

```
<f:validateBean disabled="true" />
```

Make sure that you have none of them.

---

**Update**: as per your update, you've made a classic mistake: you've put the submit button in a different form than the input fields. The submit button needs to go in the same form as the input fields which you would like to send along with the submit.

Comment: strange thing that i don't have any of the two guesses, any other ideas ?

Comment: Well, then apparently the process validations phase is completely skipped for the input components. Don't you have an `immediate="true"` on the command button?

Comment: Your command button is in a different form. Surely it won't submit the inputs of another form. Put the inputs and the commands in the **same** form. Strangely enough this is exactly what you've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230451/how-to-add-iceselectmanycheckbox-to-a-icedatatable/8257067#8257067) to another question with similar problem today and also asked to me in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p/2524832#comment10160524_2524832) for confirmation...