# How to create a JSF table with checkboxes?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create a JSF table like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-delete-row-in-jsf-datatable/). But instead delete button in every row I want to place check box in every row in the first column because I want to delete more than one row simultaneously. How I can create such a row and delete button which deletes every selected row? And can this be done with AJAX? I don't want to refresh the page.

Best wishes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want an example that uses `f:ajax` and since other answer uses the given example in [How to use JSF's h:selectBooleanCheckbox with h:dataTable to create one object per row?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524832/1216609) which is aimed for jsf 1 (and not 2) you can modify the delete button into something like this (make use of the `f:ajax`)

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete Selected">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{bean.submit}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and change `public void submit()` into `public void submit(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev)`

Comment: Listener is not necessary. Method can also just be kept in `<h:commandButton action>`.

Answer (score 3):

Balusc has a great tutorial about datatables in JSF.
One part is about row selection with checkboxes:
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SelectMultipleRows