# iterating selectBooleanCheckbox in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable, crud

I am creating a JSF app in which I am getting a list of users from a DB in a `DataTable. I am showing`selectBooleanCheckbox` in front of the user, and I want to implement a bulk delete option so the user can select multiple users and press the delete button. If it is PHP I can do that easily, but right now I dont know what to do.

Do I need to create a `selectBooleanCheckbox` in bean as well and bind it? I am looking forward for a best approach. BalusC's approach for CRUD is not applicable here as he is using custom DAO stuff.

Comment: I must say "father of j2EE" and pioneer for omnifaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this post, [How to use <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> in <h:dataTable> to select multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p?rq=1) Hope this finds you good.
It explains every step required to handle the checkboxes.