# map for h:selectbooleancheckbox with datatable returns size of 0

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have this scenario that each row of datatable has checkbox.
if checkbox is selected you can delete multiple data and edit only one data.

I am successfully able to implement the delete but I got stuck with the edit cause checkedID will return the size of 0.

for the records I am following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p/2524832#2524832)

below is my codes:

list.xhtml

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{transportationController.prepareEdit()}"/>
               <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{transportationController.delete()}">

<p:dataTable value="#{transportationController.items}" var="item"                  <p:column>
              <f:facet name="header">
              </f:facet>
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{transportationTypeController.checkedID[item.id]}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
              <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
              </f:facet>
              <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
              <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Remark"/>
              </f:facet>
              <h:outputText value="#{item.remark}"/>
            </p:column>
          </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

managedbean ---> transportationcontroller.java
transportationcontroller is a sessionscoped

```
private Map<Integer, Boolean> checkedID = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
  private List<Transportation> transportation = new ArrayList<Transportation>();

//setters and getters.

public List<Transportation> getCheckedTransportation() {
    List<Transportation> checkedItems = new ArrayList<Transportation>();
    for (Transportation trans : transportation) {
      if (checkedID.get(trans.getId())) {
        checkedItems.add(trans);
      }
    }
    checkedID.clear();
    return checkedItems;
  }

//delete function

public String delete() {
    List<Transportation> list = getCheckedTransportation();
    if (list.size() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ejbFacade.remove(list.get(i));
      }
      return "List";
    } else {
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select data", "Please select data");
      JsfUtil.getCurrent().addMessage("warning-message", msg);
      return null;
    }
  }

//edit function

public void prepareEdit() {
      List<Transportation> list = getCheckedTransportation();
      if (list.size() == 1) {
        current = list.get(0);
      } else {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select at least one data", "Please select at least one data");
        JsfUtil.getCurrent().addMessage("warning-message", msg);
     }

  }

public Transportation getSelected() {

    if (current == null) {
      current = new Transportation();
      selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
  }
```

entity class ---> Transportation.java

```
public class Transportation implements Serializable{
@Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

//etc..
}
```

as I debug,the Map checkedID will always has size of 0 for edit but for delete it's working fine. I've been stuck on this for this hours now but I am not able to identify the problem as why checkedID always has size of 0 which is for edit only when it's working fine for delete. anyhelp would be appreciated. Thanks.

> Note: i know that primefaces p:datatable has selectionMode="multiple"
>   and selections but I don't to use it. I only want to use primefaces
>   for it's pagination.

Comment: For your `delete()` method, `getCheckedTransportation()` always returns a list of size 0. Did I understand you correct?

Comment: for prepareEdit() only.. for delete() it's working fine. I just included the delete function for reference in case someone would ask.

Comment: How is `Transportationcontroller` scoped? Please add the annotations or configuration to your question.

Comment: PrimeFaces data table has builtin row selection facilities by `<p:dataTable selection>` and `<p:column selectionMode>`. Why don't you make use of it? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl it's a sessionscoped.

Comment: @BalusC yeah primefaces has but i don't like the style of it's checkboxes. I only use primefaces for datatable and it's pagination. I wan't simple checkboxes.

Comment: Have you tried to print list.size() in both method as it seems that both button are calling different method but the size of list inside both button should be same

Comment: can't print list.size() because the method getCheckedTransportation() returns null.