# NullPointerException while displaying the same page after some taks in jsf

Tags: jsf

First I want to tell :

- I saw [How to use JSF's h:selectBooleanCheckbox with h:dataTable to create one object per row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p)
  and my problem is like same but not solved problem.

Following is my code :

***.xhtml**

```
<rich:column>
     <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="resolveTxn" value="#{verifyTransactionBean.checked[verifyTxnList.id]}"/>
</rich:column>
.
.//Some code here
.
<h:commandButton value="Resolve" action="#{verifyTransactionBean.resolveToTxn}"  styleClass="btn" />
```

and following is my code

```
private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

public void resolveToTxn() {
    List<ToVerifyTxnDTO> list = new ArrayList<ToVerifyTxnDTO>();
    for (ToVerifyTxnDTO dTO : toVerifyTxnDTOList) {
        if(checked.get(dTO.getId())){//I got null pointer exception here
           Long id=dTO.getId(); 
           verifyTransactionSessionBeanLocal.updateResolvedflag(id);
        }
    }

}
```

**What I want to do ?**

I want to pass checked row id as parameter on following :

```
verifyTransactionSessionBeanLocal.updateResolvedflag(id);
```

And after clicking the button `Resolve` some operation should be done and refresh `dataTable` and display same page. Operation is done but getting `null pointer exception` while displaying (Reddering) the same page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if ()` test on a `Boolean` will throw `NullPointerException` if the `Boolean` itself is actually `null` instead of `true` or `false`. In other words, the        `checked.get(dTO.getId())` has unexpectedly returned `null` for some reason.

That can have several causes:

- The JSF implementation hasn't properly updated the `checked` map with the value from `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` for some reason.
- The EL implementation was using `Boolean` instead of `boolean` for some reason.
- The `toVerifyTxnDTOList` has incompatibly changed during the process which caused that the currently iterated `dTO` isn't the one which was been displayed in the table at the moment checkboxes were clicked (perhaps because the bean is request scoped instead of view scoped).
- The `toVerifyTxnDTOList` contains more items than present in the `checked` map because you're using pagination and displaying only a subset at once.

In any case, to fix the `NullPointerException`, just add an additional nullcheck:

```
Boolean dtoChecked = checked.get(dTO.getId());

if (dtoChecked != null && dtoChecked) {
    // ...
}
```

This however doesn't fix the underlying cause of your problem. My best guess would be that the `toVerifyTxnDTOList` contains more items than actually being displayed in the table. Thus, it's one of the last mentioned two causes mentioned in the list. The first mentioned two causes are theoretically possible, but in practice I haven't seen this before.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I believe the problem is one of the first two causes BalusC mentioned