# jsf datatable with selectbooleancheckbox

Tags: jsf, datatable, submit

I have following code:
JSF PAGE

```
<h:dataTablevalue="#{bean.records}" var="app">
  <h:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[app.id]}"/>
    <f:facet name="footer">
      <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submitPublic}"/>
    </f:facet>
</h:column>
```

and BEAN code:

```
@SessionScoped
public class bean 

private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
private List<Application> checkedItems = new ArrayList<Application>();

public void submit() {

for (Application app : getRecords()) {
    if (checked.get(app.getId())) {
        checkedItems.add(app);
    }
}
checked.clear();
//here logic for selected apps
}

    public Map<Long, Boolean> getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
    public void setChecked(Map<Long, Boolean> checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
```

problem is when I click button, selected values are not submitted.
I was reading this article:
[How to use <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> in <h:dataTable> to select multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p)

did everything the same way, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the datatable when the `Checkbox` is selected.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[app.id]}">
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" render=":YOUR_FORM_ID:YOUR_TABLE_ID"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: well... it worked. thank you. Could you explain why my code wasn't working?

Comment: I am sorry for my explanation. Try to learn `JSF Request Processing Life Cycle`.