# How to make selection and Edit Row working in Primefaces 4.0

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am completely new to Primefaces and jsf. I am facing problems in selection of row and editing row together. I have datatable.

```
<p:dataTable  var="adminFileConfiguartionModel" value="#{adminFileController.adminFileConfigDataModel}" id="adminFileConfigID" editable="true" selection="#{adminFileController.adminFileSelectList}">  
    <p:ajax  event="rowEdit" listener="#{adminFileController.onEdit}"  update=":fileConfigForm:messages,:fileConfigurationForm:adminFileConfigID"  />
<p:column id="checkBox" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%"  />
```

'adminFileSelectList' is ArrayList .. when i complete editing part ,checked box is unchecked but still after submitting button previous value is stored in  rowKey ..which i get from getRowData(String rowKey)... how to nullify that previous value..

Comment: Have you take a look to : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml ?

Comment: @Lamq , in that link only editing is there..no selection...i mean checkboxs.. ..

Comment: Could you post your code bean and xhtml. When i have to face to checkbox inside datatable i have follow this example from balusC :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p/2524832#2524832