# What is pre-requisite for value attribute of h:selectBooleanCheckbox to be rendered to HTML

Tags: javascript, jsf, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a managed bean which contains a list of ids. When I iterate through that list using a data table, I use a h:selectBooleanCheckbox and assign the id value to it like this:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value = "#{managedBean.objectMap[<objectKey>]}">
```

However, after the page is rendered, I don't see the value attribute being rendered. So I wanted to know why it is not being rendered?

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *However, after the page is rendered, I don't see the value attribute being rendered. So I wanted to know why it is not being rendered?*

Because it's not relevant in order to trigger a `Boolean`. Just the request parameter being `null` or non-`null` depending on HTML `checked` state is sufficient to represent a `Boolean`. The `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` doesn't support non-`Boolean` values anyway.

If you're absolutely positive you need a checkbox value, use either `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` with only a single item.

```html
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedValues}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{bean.someValue}" itemLabel="#{null}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Or if it's actually for JavaScript purposes (I'm just guessing because you confusingly tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) on a JSF question without explaining its relevance anywhere), then you could also use a HTML5 `data` attribute which you can set as passthrough attribute (requires JSF 2.2).

```html
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.someBoolean}" a:data-value="#{bean.someValue}" />
```

It'll be available in JS as below:

```
var value = element.dataset.value;
```

Or jQuery:

```
var value = $(element).data("value");
```

#### See also:

- [How to use <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> in <h:dataTable> to select multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524514/how-to-use-jsfs-hselectbooleancheckbox-with-hdatatable-to-create-one-object-p/)